# Time-Field: not configured in Kibana

Tags: kibana, timefield

It can happen you have "Time-field: not configured" in kibana when you hit settings on Discover tag.

[image]

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the index don't forget to fulfill the "Timefield Name"

[image]

Hope it helps!

PS. I give for granted that you have a field like "@timestamp" already